# How to let mktmpdir delete directory on Windows?

Tags: ruby, windows, unit-testing, minitest

This is my test:

```
class TestFoo < Minitest::Test
  def test_basic
    Dir.mktmpdir 'test' do |dir|
      f = File.join(dir, 'foo.txt')
      File.write(f, "Hello")
      assert_equal(File.exist?(f))
      File.delete(f)
    end
  end
end
```

Works just fine on Ubuntu. However, on Windows:

```
TestFoo#test_basic:
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ dir_s_rmdir - D:/a/_temp/test20220612-6584-7fpeor
    C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.4/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:1460:in `rmdir'
    C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.4/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:1460:in `block in remove_dir1'
    C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.4/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:1474:in `platform_support'
    C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Ruby/3.0.4/x64/lib/ruby/3.0.0/fileutils.rb:1459:in 
...
```